# Nested templates with KnockoutJS and MVC 3.0

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to knockout JS, but am enjoying every bit that I am learning each day.

Here is my question. Based on the [Loading and saving data](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) tutorial, let's say that I have the following classes in my MVC 3.0 view model:

```
public class MasterModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ParentModel> Parents { get; set; }
}

public class ParentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And that my Index() method of the HomeController returns an instance of MasterModel with a list of ParentModel, each in turn containing a list of ChildModel. On the client side, I have the following view:

```
@model SomeNamespace.Models.MasterModel

(...)

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var initialData = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
    var viewModel = {
        parents: ko.observableArray(initialData.Parents),
    (...)
    };
```

I would like to be able to use nested templates to display the list of ParentModel bound to the MasterModel and for each ParentModel, the list of ChildrenModel. I also want both lists (ParentModel and ChildrenModel) to be observable arrays so that items of each list can be added or removed dynamically.

I have attempted to implement this following the ["template" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) article on the Knockout JS site, but am not sure how to implement the observable array containing a list of... observable arrays...

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/majorbyte/yEX7k/) should be able to help you on the way, it works like this:

```html
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'TopTemplate' , foreach: masters}"></ul> 
<script type="text/html" id="TopTemplate">
    <li >    
        <p>${name}</p>
        <ul data-bind=" template: {name:  'NestedTemplate' , foreach:  parents } " style="list-style-type:circle;margin-left:15px">
        </ul>
    </li> 

</script>
<script type="text/html" id="NestedTemplate">         
    <li>
        <p>${name}</p>
        <ul data-bind=" template: {name:  'parentTemplate' , foreach:  children } " style="list-style-type:circle;margin-left:15px">
        </ul>
    </li>
</script>
 <script type="text/html" id="parentTemplate">         
    <li>
        <p>${name}</p>
    </li>
</script>
```

And this code:

```
var viewModel = {
    masters: ko.observableArray([
        {
        name: "Master1",
        parents: [{
            name: "Parent 1",
             children : [{
                name: "chlid 1"},
            {
                name: "child 2"}]},
        {
            name: "Parent 2",
             children : [{
                name: "chlid 1"},
            {
                name: "child 2"}]}]},
    {
        name: "Master2",
         parents: [{
            name: "Parent 3",
             children : [{
                name: "chlid 1"},
            {
                name: "child 2"}]},
        {
            name: "Parent 4",
             children : [{
                name: "chlid 1"},
            {
                name: "child 2"}]}]}     ])
};

// ko magic...
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Hi, this is definitely the way to go, but from my example, how would I convert my **initialData** variable into the masters, parents and children you suggest? I guess my problem might be more related to javascript than knockout at this point... :-)

Comment: Your **initialData** would look almost the same. I mocked that Json structure under the assumption `@IEnumerable<model SomeNamespace.Models.MasterModel>`, my mistake. Using `@model SomeNamespace.Models.MasterModel` your json would not be an array, just one Master object containing 3 properties (Id, Description and an array called Parents). Also note that in the example I gave, it's only the masters array that it observed there, so UI will react upon changes to that array (push/pop etc. of master objects). Look into this: [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: Awesome, the mapping plugin is exactly what I needed. Many thanks!